# How to tell the difference between a voltage regulator in an SOT89 sized SMD and a transistor same package

Tags: transistors, circuit-analysis, voltage-regulator

[image: Panasonic servo driver blown mini board]
[image: Panasonic servo driver]
[image: Panasonic servo driver - good mini boards]
Newbie here with just enough knowledge to be dangerous.  I have a Mazak Laser, vintage 1990 with Panasonic servo drivers, 3 axis. One of the power transistors went out which tripped two breakers and when I turned them back on an SMD, size SOT89, blew up and I'm trying to determine whether it is a voltage regulator or a transistor so that I can replace it.

There are 11 other miniature boards identical to the blown one on the main driver board and I was barely able to determine the part numbers on the chips as being XL31, which I could not find in any database or web search.

Since I have so many other examples for comparison I was wondering how to measure the good components to see what they are and then find (hopefully!) something local (Radio Shack?) to replace the bad component. Of course an identical part is near impossible to find but there must be other components that perform the same function, just not as small and neatly as the SMD.

Comment: Photo please... There are many different components that come in SOT89 packages, so a photo of the part and another of the surrounding circuitry to give it some context are required.

Answer (score 1):

You need to find an smd code book that has that 2 letter code in it.

The first two letters are the code, the second two numbers are the date (usually).

[This](http://www.smdcode.com/en/smd/code/xl-2sd1614-l-silicon-npn-transistor-107998/) looks like it is your part.  SOT89 sized, XL code (the second two numbers are a date stamp or a batch number).

Comment: That's fantastic - thank you! Now what off the shelf component can I use to replace the blown one?

Comment: Check out [this](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/18692/how-can-i-find-a-replacement-for-a-transistor) response.  It goes over how to find a replacement for a transistor.